# STL and TR1 on mobile devices

Tags: c++, mobile, stl

I'm newbie in developing apps for smartphones, but have lots of experience writing desktop applications using STL and TR1.

Is it possible to use these libraries when developing using:

1. Official iOS development tools
2. Android NDK
3. Marmalade (former Airplay SDK)

Comment: There is no library called STL :)

Comment: I do understand that STL and TR1 are just standards and can have different implementations. So, if it is critical I can change wording of my question to "Are these standards implemented in following SDKs?".

Comment: There is no standard called STL :-)

Comment: If STL is not a library (despite being standard template Library) nor a standard (despite being described in C++ standard) then what proper english word for it?

Comment: @Sergey: the standard library for C++ is called the "C++ standard library". Parts of it are based on an ancient library called "STL"; if you use that term, then we have to guess whether you mean the standard library, the specific parts of it that are based on the ancient library, or the ancient library itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C++03 STL is available on both iOS and the Android NDK. Much of TR1 is also available for both, as they both use GCC 4.x.

I'm not familiar with Marmalade.

Comment: How can we include TR1 in our android ndk project?

Comment: `#include <tr1/whichever_header_you_need>` typically.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use STL classes and Boost libraries in iOS and Android apps. That includes TR1 classes as well, I presume.